# LINQ Modify XML document

Tags: c#, linq

I need to modify an XML file containing product sales.
I tried to do this with LINQ, however it doesn't work. I have the following file

```
<SalesProducts>
    <ProductSale>
        <Sale type="Fixed">
        <ProductId>22</ProductId>
        <Value>50</Value>
    </ProductSale>
    <ProductSale>
        <Sale type="Discount">
        <ProductId>32</ProductId>
        <Value>33</Value>
    </Product>
</SalesProducts>
```

I want to add another ProductSale item after the item where product id is equal to 22.

I tried the following query.

```
var elProd = docX.Element("SalesProducts").
    Elements("ProductSale").
    Where(e => ((string)e.Element("ProductId")) == "22");

elProd.AddAfterSelf(
    new XElement("Sale", ""),
    new XElement("Value", "43"),
    new XElement("ProductId", "154")));
```

But this doesn't work.
Also I can't add attribute to Sale element.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output ? Please update the OP with expected output

Comment: Your XML is completely not well-formed.

Answer (score 2):

`elProd` is a Collection of `XElement`. This is the reason you are not able to use `elProd.AddAfterSelf` as the method is defined for `XElement` and not for `IEnumerable<XElement>.`

Since you are searching for specific Product, you could use `Single()`(Assuming there is no duplicate `ProductID`) to ensure only the desired element is selected.

```
var elProd = docX.Element("SalesProducts")
                 .Elements("ProductSale")
                 .Single(e => ((string)e.Element("ProductId") == "22"));
```

Or

```
var elProd = docX.Descendants("ProductSale")
                 .Single(e => ((string)e.Element("ProductId") == "22"));
```

Once you have selected the desired element, you can now use `AddAfterSelf` to add the new Element. Please note you need to create an `XElement` ProductSale, with Sale/Value/ProductID as child.

```
elProd.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("ProductSale",
            new XElement("Sale", new XAttribute("type", "Type of sale")),
            new XElement("Value", "43"),
            new XElement("ProductId", "154")));
```

Output Sample

```
<SalesProducts>
  <ProductSale>
    <Sale type="Fixed"></Sale>
    <ProductId>22</ProductId>
    <Value>50</Value>
  </ProductSale>
  <ProductSale>
    <Sale type="Type of sale" />
    <Value>43</Value>
    <ProductId>154</ProductId>
  </ProductSale>
  <ProductSale>
    <Sale type="Discount"></Sale>
    <ProductId>32</ProductId>
    <Value>33</Value>
  </ProductSale>
</SalesProducts>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use overload of [First](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_First__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method:

```
var first = xml.Elements().First(n => n.Element("ProductId").Value == "22");
first.AddAfterSelf(XElement.Parse(@"<ProductSale><Sale type='Discount'/><Value>43</Value><ProductId>154</ProductId></ProductSale>"));
```